# using protractor for performance testing

Tags: protractor, performance-testing

I am having a terrible time trying to get decent from end timing numbers using Protractor. I have tried using **protractor-perf**, but the timings from that don't seem to really reflect the reality of the page load time. It says that the "Program" metric is the total time, however I am seeing it report timings much faster that what you actually see when running the test manually.

I have also tried creating my own timer, and that is proving very difficult based on the controlFlow and all the promises.

Has anyone done any performance testing with Protractor? Is there any good guidance to follow when trying to get timings? Has anyone successfully implemented a timer?

Comment: I'm not super familiar with protractor-perf. Could things be faster because protractor is disabling animations/timers etc? I'm assuming you'd just keep these (artificial) benchmarks and check against them for regression. They wouldn't be a substitute for manual "feel" testing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use your own timers, you just have to insert them into the control flow right before and after the functions you are trying to measure:

```
var startTime;
browser.controlFlow().execute(function() {
    startTime = Date.now();
});
element(by.css('#startThing')).click();
element(by.css('#endThing')).getText();
browser.controlFlow().execute(function() {
    var endTime = Date.now();
    var elapsed = endTime - startTime;
    console.log('clicking the startThing until getText of the endThing = ' + elapsed + 'ms);
});
```